# Modify docx with script

Tags: docx, pandoc

Best way to modify generated docx document with scripting language?

I thought about Python/Ruby or maybe something from MS --- hmmm VB.Script? PowerShell?

I don't want to do that in MS's tech. If its really super easy with Microsoft's technologies, then ok, I could try, but if not, Python/Ruby would be better.

Pandoc gives me some errors during conversion docx->*, and the other way around (simple.md -> *.docx), the output is unreadable in MS Word 2013 (file corrupted or something like that).

Comment: Pandoc doesn't convert *from* docx, only *to*.  I don't have MS Word 2013 to test with, but if you are experiencing problems with pandoc's docx output, please open an issue on the [bug tracker](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues).

Comment: Pandoc *does* convert from docx - I used it to reverse-engineer a docx file to markdown using v1.14.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library for natively creating and manipulating docx files [here](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx).

Personally I would pick another, non-propitiatory, format such as rst or latex and then use pandoc to convert to whatever else was needed.  Keep in mind that .docx format **only** works with MS-Word and only with recent versions.  I have successfully converted to docx, html and pdf from .rst files using pandoc.

You might also like to take a look at docutils for a pure python way of generating documents.

Comment: I've seen it. Played a bit and it seems to be quite limited. I'll try to play a little more with it.